# Java check - charset, encoding of html page - like browsers do

Tags: java, browser, unicode, character-encoding

How to check what really charset, encoding of some html page ?
For example, the charset of some html page is iso-8859-1,
 but the content of the html written with utf8

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
...
here is content with utf8
...
</html>
```

How to check it, Is it possible to check with java charset, encoding of html page, 
like it's done in browsers ?

Thank you !

Comment: A page like that is in error. If it specifies `charset=iso-8859-1` it must not contain utf-8 encoded stuff in the body.

Comment: You cannot know what is really the encoding of a page unless you know what content the page is supposed to have.

Comment: So, how browser knows ... ?